# UI breaking after page refresh in Blazor

Tags: jquery, blazor, blazor-server-side

Below is the code snippet. Page works fine first time when loaded. And if I navigate to another page and come back to the same page, the Jscript file doesn't work. How to fix this?

```
 private IJSObjectReference? module;

 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
 {
    if (firstRender)
    {
        module = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "/app-assets/js/scripts/page.js");
    }
 }
```

Comment: What function do you want to call from this file? Complete your code

Comment: Surely `firstRender` won't be true if it's not firstRender?  (I'm not a blazor developer, so maybe it's set on navigate back, seems unlikely - navigate back generally doesn't involve server-side)

Comment: " Jscript file doesn't work."  You need to be more specific.  You are calling a function called `import` and passing it a string.  Are you saying that `import` isn't called when you return to the page and it reloads?